# Clean up a map in XDP program

Tags: linux, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I would like to clean up data in the map (bloomfilter in my case) every X seconds but I couldn't find any function which would allow me to do so: looks like there are only `pop_elem` functions [kernel/bpf/helpers.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/helpers.c#n1591).
What could be the workaround for this problem? Like reload the eBPF program (don't know if it is expensive performance-wise) or somehow clean up the shared memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting from bloom filters is not supported, [here](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/20210921210225.4095056-2-joannekoong@fb.com/) is the original commit which says:

> Deleting an element in the bloom filter map is not supported

The only way to reset a bloom filter map is to replace it with a new map. The commit also states:

> The bloom filter map may be used as an inner map.

So I suggest using a map-in-map array/hash map and replacing the inner map once in a while, and adding back the desired entries.You can create the new map while the old one is still being used and swap out once you are ready. Performance depends on the amount of entries to add to the new map.

Comment: Note it's not specific to the BPF implementation. Bloom filters don't support deleting elements from the set; once added, there is no way to remove.